# Bootstrap CSS Carousel Not working after float?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am implementing a carousel in bootstrap but I am having two problems.

1. It is not aligned horizontally (my div are going downwards).
2. It is not working when I used the `float: left` property.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried a variety of things to fix this, but nothing seems to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="internships" id="internships">
  <div class="container headings text-center mt-4">
    <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold font-size mb-4">
      Internships</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3 ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12 ">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12">
            <div class="box">
              <a href="#"><img src="Images/IMG.jpg" class="img-fluid" srcset=""></a>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur error tempora maxime, suscipit dolorem asperiores ! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i don't know on what element you added the float, but it would be normal a float on your items will break the carousel.

Comment: It's in 1st div element as d-d flex row

Comment: I think because you've missed a closing tag...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you would like ?

[image: testing]

If it is, then you have to **work on some initial bootstrap** classes to find a work-around the `active` class.

**Why ?**

The `active` class passes the element on `display : block` when you want to use a `row` (which uses `display : flex`). So every time you're item is `active`, it goes back to being a `block` and sets **vertically**.

Then when you'll use the **buttons**, it will trigger the `carousel.item-next` / `carousel.item-prev` classes and they also use... `display : block` ! So you'll need to change them to `display : flex` too.

---

This is what you'll need in your **CSS** :

```
.carousel-item.active{
    display: flex;
}
.carousel-item-next{
    display: flex;
}
.carousel-item-prev{
    display: flex;
}
```

---

Then you'll need to work on your **HTML** :

you'll need to change the `carousel-item` class to : `<div class="carousel-item active row">`

inside that row, the children must be set using widths/cols from bootstrap. Such as : `<div class="col-3>`  (3 if you want it to use one fourth of the carousel - it's what i used on the image up there)

Finally, here's a picture illustrating the HTML part, you'll need to **repeat** the HTML for **each slide** you'll be using :

[image: Second picture to illustrate the HTML]

Comment: I want to use carousel  which display items horizontally but in this case ..items are in vertical position and also carousel is not working

Comment: Why not use the bootstrap documentation regarding carousels ? I thin you're missing bootstrap classes and divs to make your carousel work properly, please compare you're code to the docs here : 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#with-indicators

Meanwhile, i'm going to try to code something that i believe is what you're looking for

Comment: @AlexPandian I upadted my answer, please keep us updated of your progress too :)

Comment: Yup Still working on it @https://stackoverflow.com/users/14597146/milandemoniack